# Multiple choice quiz in python using random function and lists

Tags: python, list, loops, random, multiple-choice

I'm trying to make a multiple choice quiz using python. It seemed like something simple to make at first but now i'm scratching my head a lot trying to figure out how to do certain things.

I am using two lists; one for the questions and one for the answers. I would like to make it so that a random question is chosen from the questions list, as well as 2 random items from the answers list (wrong answers) and finally the correct answer (which has the same index as the randomly selected question).
I've got as far as selecting a random question and two random wrong answers

- My first problem is getting the program to display the correct answer.
- The second problem is how to check whether the user enters the correct answer or not.

I would appreciate any feedback for my code. I'm very new to this so go a little easy please! 
I hope my stuff is readable (sorry it's a bit long)

thanks in advance

```
import random

print ("Welcome to your giongo quiz\n")
x=0
while True:
    def begin(): # would you like to begin? yes/no... leaves if no
        wanna_begin = input("Would you like to begin?: ").lower()
        if wanna_begin == ("yes"):
            print ("Ok let's go!\n")
            get_username()#gets the user name
        elif wanna_begin != ("no") and wanna_begin != ("yes"):
            print ("I don't understand, please enter yes or no:")
            return begin()
        elif wanna_begin == ("no"):
            print ("Ok seeya!")
    break

def get_username(): #get's username, checks whether it's the right length, says hello 
    username = input("Please choose a username (1-10 caracters):")
    if len(username)>10 or len(username)<1:
        print("Username too long or too short, try again")
        return get_username()
    else:
        print ("Hello", username, ", let's get started\n\n") 
        return randomq(questions)

##########

questions = ["waku waku", "goro goro", "kushu", "bukubuku", "wai-wai", "poro", "kipashi", "juru", "pero"]

answers = ["excited", "cat purring", "sneezing", "bubbling", "children playing", "teardrops falling", "crunch", "slurp", "licking"]

score = 0

if len(questions) > 0: #I put this here because if i left it in ONly inside the function, it didnt work...
        random_item = random.randint(0, len(questions)-1)
        asked_question = questions.pop(random_item)

###########

def randomq(questions):
    if len(questions) > 0:
        random_item = random.randint(0, len(questions)-1)
        asked_question = questions.pop(random_item)
        print ("what does this onomatopea correspond to?\n\n%s" % asked_question, ":\n" )
        return choices(answers, random_item)
    else:
        print("You have answered all the questions")
        #return final_score

def choices(answers, random_item):
    random_item = random.randint(0, len(questions)-1)
    a1 = answers.pop(random_item)
    a2 = answers.pop(random_item)
    possible_ans = [a1, a2, asked_question"""must find way for this to be right answer"""]
    random.shuffle(possible_ans)
    n = 1
    for i in possible_ans:
        print (n, "-", i) 
        n +=1
    choice = input("Enter your choice :")
    """return check_answer(asked_question, choice)"""

    a = questions.index(asked_question)
    b = answers.index(choice)
    if a == b:
        return True
    return False

begin()
```

Comment: As you note, your code is long. You should reduce it to a [mcve]. You may want to read [ask]. Then describe your attempt to solve the *specific* problem and what deviates from your expectations.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! i'll try and be more minimal next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use another list(for example `correct_answer` or such) to record the correct answer for each question. Then instead of using `a1 = answers.pop(random_item)` to choose a wrong answer, use

```
while True:
    if answer[random.randint(0, len(answers)-1)] != correct_answer[question]:
        break
a1 = answers.pop(id)
```

to avoid choosing the correct answer as an incorrect one.

#### EDIT

As your correct answer is already in the `answers`, you should not pop items when choosing some incorrect answers, otherwise it will break the indices.

You can choose two wrong answers and a correct answer like this.

```
correct = question_index

while True:
    wrong1 = random.randint(0, len(answers)-1)
    if wrong1 != correct:
        break

while True:
    wrong2 = random.randint(0, len(answers)-1)
    if wrong1 != wrong2 and wrong1 != correct:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could structure the data in a simpler way, using dictionaries. Each item is a pair of a key and a value, for more info refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).
For example your data will look like this (each question is associated with an answer):

```
data = {'question1': 'answer1', 'question2': 'answer2'}
```

Then we can loop through this dictionary to print the answers after we randomly choose a question. Here's some sudo code for help:

```
# Choose a random question

# Print all the answers in the dictionary
for key, value in data.iteritems(): #its data.items() in Python 3.x
     print value

# If the choice matches the answer
pop the question from the dictionary and do whatever you want to do

# Else, ask again
```

For more information about iterating through a dictionary refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops).

Comment: thanks for your response! 
I did think I could do it like this, maybe I will try